# FB images resolution

Tags: facebook

I noticed a strange thing on Facebook. 
I have uploaded 3840 X 2400 image to Facebook.When I downloaded the same image from Facebook, I got an image of 2048 X 1280(Compression ratio = 1.8) . Uploaded 2560 X 1600 and got 960 X 600(Compression ratio = 2.6).I uploaded 1440 X 1280 and got 960 X 854(Compression ratio = 1.5).Why are my images scaled? To what percentage, the image is scaled? Also, what is the option "High Quality"? What happens if we select that option? Can any one explain me? I went through [GRAPH API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/) but couldn't find any clue...

Comment: it depends also on the filesize.
you can read a little explanation here: https://www.facebook.com/help/www/266520536764594

Comment: but when I uploaded 800 X 480, I got the same width and height...